# Can the shift in grammatical usage of "an X-ese [person]" be explained linguistically?

Tags: sociolinguistics, parts-of-speech, history, anthropology

While reading *An Introduction to Information Theory* by John R. Pierce, I was distracted by a linguistic artifact (on page 251 of the second edition):

> We can tell our friends apart, […] but we find much less that is distinctive in strangers. We can, of course, tell a Chinese from our Caucasian friends, but this does not enable us to enjoy variety among Chinese.

Referring to an individual as `a Chinese` is *no longer* grammatically correct. When the book was written (1961) and revised (1980), the grammar apparently was as proper as `I met a Brazilian.` might be today (2019). Now it sounds at least as wrong as `My friend is a French.` — if not also offensive. (The explicit attention drawn to race in the passage certainly makes the language stand out. The author was illustrating a larger point: "To be distinguishable, sounds must be to a degree familiar").

I found a number of discussions regarding the *current* grammaticality of this phenomenon:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391986/can-i-say-a-chinese-in-english
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509677/is-sentence-i-am-a-chinese-correct
- https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183/why-is-a-japanese-offensive
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194684/why-can-we-say-an-american-but-not-a-british

Several of the answers note a pattern in the word ending, e.g. "In English there is a distinction between nationalities that end in 'ian' like Canadian or Italian and those that end in 'ese' like Japanese or Burmese."

So there is a rule via which we might derive that "Ask a Canadian" is grammatical but "Ask a Burmese" is not. But this rule seems to have **changed**, and quite recently! A whole set of [demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) (those ending in `-ese`) shifted from use as both nouns and adjectives to proper use only as adjectives, within the lifetime of many speakers alive today.

I am curious as to why this shift happened. Was it a conscious change? Has this particular case been formally studied from a linguistics perspective? Are there other examples where a production rule related to *morphemic* inflection has changed for reasons [which I suspect are] unrelated to pronunciation?

Comment: The only explanation is: analogy.